# Disallow chrome dev tools to index folder structure on sources panel

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

Hey guys Iv searched all over maybe Im not using the right terms. Im trying to stop the index off my wordpress site tree structure like `wp-content` `wp-content\plugins` etc on the sources panel in chrome dev tools, but with no luck. Iv tried adding some `.htaccess` rules to solve the issue. hope someone could help cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "google"? The company? The Chrome browser? If it's the latter you can exclude file paths in devtools settings -> Workspace section.

Comment: You right I meant chrome dev tools, but this setting will only change it in my end only wont it?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+hide+wp_content).